# rabbitmq (ArgumentError) argument error

Tags: rabbitmq

It is my first using rabbitmq,I download erlang 9.3 and rabbitmq 3.7.4,and also configure my path with erl and rabbitmq,It seems well as I enter commend line and use `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`,but when i use `rabbitmqctl start_app`,it occur to an argument error,like this:

> Starting node rabbit@DESKTOP-0T1B7S8 ...
>   ** (ArgumentError) argument error
>       (stdlib) io_lib.erl:170: :io_lib.format(' * effective user\'s home directory: ~s~n', [[67, 58, 92, 85, 115, 101, 114, 115, 92, 19975, 23480, 26827]])
>       src/rabbit_misc.erl:670: :rabbit_misc."-format_many/1-lc$^0/1-0-"/1
>       src/rabbit_misc.erl:670: :rabbit_misc."-format_many/1-lc$^0/1-0-"/1
>       src/rabbit_misc.erl:670: :rabbit_misc.format_many/1
>       (rabbitmqctl) lib/rabbitmqctl.ex:349: RabbitMQCtl.get_node_diagnostics/1
>       (rabbitmqctl) lib/rabbitmqctl.ex:307: RabbitMQCtl.format_error/3
>       (rabbitmqctl) lib/rabbitmqctl.ex:43: RabbitMQCtl.main/1
>       (elixir) lib/kernel/cli.ex:76: anonymous fn/3 in Kernel.CLI.exec_fun/2

I use win10 and my path is 
erl:  `D:\RabbitMQ\erl9.3\bin`

rabbitmq:  `D:\RabbitMQ\rabbitMQ\rabbitmq_server-3.7.4\sbin`

Actually,my computer's username used to be chinese and now I change it to english,it also doesn't work.Now I think my path hasn't non-ASCII charactor.

I have no idea with this problem,can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: What operating system are you using? What is the value of your home directory? It appears that the name of your home directory may have non-ASCII characters in it - see 19975, 23480 and 26827 in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can see your 'C:\Users\username' is not English . change it to English.

Answer (score -1):

```
'C:\Users\username'
```

My computer 'username' is Chinese, so we need stop RebbitMQ service, then execute the following 3 statements:

```
rabbitmq-service.bat remove
set RABBITMQ_BASE=D:\install3\rabbitmq\rabbitmq_server-3.7.8\data
rabbitmq-service.bat install
```

RABBITMQ_BASE is my storage path of db and log, now it works very well.